# Tomcat does not exclude JARs specified in tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, dockerfile, tomcat8

I'm trying to set a Tomcat configuration setting through an environment variable. It works for some, it seems not to work for others.

Specifically I'd like to exclude certain JARs from being scanned for TLD files.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.34-jre8

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8000

ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/catalinaLogging.properties -Dtomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.7.0.jar"

COPY /target/my.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/my.war
COPY /catalinaLogging.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
```

The `catalinaLogging.properties` is successfully applied because I see the difference in logging during startup. The `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` does not seem to be applied though, I still see the following in the output:

[image: screenshot]

- Do I have to set the `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` property differently?
- Do I have to use a different property altogether?

Comment: `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` is a property defined in the `TOMCAT_BASE/conf/catalina.properties` file. It is not a system property. You need to modify the `catalina.properties` file, if you want to list *more* jar files to skip than is already listed in there.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. If I had no access to that file, is there no way to configure that from the outside, through an environment variable?

Comment: Why would you have access to the script running tomcat, but not the tomcat configuration files? That makes no sense.

Comment: My example here is a dockerized version of our app. In production it runs on Azure as a managed service.

Comment: If you could explain how the `java.util.logging.config.file` is different from the `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` and why one can be set via `CATALINA_OPTS` but not the other, that would be awesome.

Comment: If you cannot modify `TOMCAT_BASE/conf/catalina.properties`, but can specify `-D` options, then you can specify an alternate location for the `catalina.properties` by setting `-Dcatalina.config=/path/to/folder/` as [documented](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Other). Just be sure to include all the values from the original file.

Answer (score 1):

`tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip` can't be configured through the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variables and has has to be configured in the `catalina.properties` instead.

The location of the `catalina.properties` however is configurable through the `-Dcatalina.config=/path/to/folder` as described by Andreas.